How do I add a CSS class to an element if selected using React?
Below I have a series of React code that has several circles displayed on a page, each with a different color. When a color is clicked, the nav displays that change by reading off the selected color.
import { useState } from "react";
const Color = ({ color, setSelectedColor}) => {
  return <div className={color} onClick={() => setSelectedColor(color)}></div>;
};


const App = () => {
  const [selectedColor, setSelectedColor] = useState("");
  return (
    <div id="container">
      <div id="navbar">
        <div>Currently selected: </div>
        <div className={selectedColor}>{selectedColor}</div>
      </div>
      <div id="colors-list">
        <Color color="violet" setSelectedColor={setSelectedColor}/>
        <Color color="orange" setSelectedColor={setSelectedColor}/>
        <Color color="yellow" setSelectedColor={setSelectedColor}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;


There is a class in CSS that I have called selected which just creates a border around a circle. The problem I am having is how exactly do I apply the class to the selectedColor? I am thinking of ternary operators, but I am new to React, so I am unsure how I should implement this.

Which element are you trying to apply that class to?  The <div> which displays the selected color, or the selectable color elements themselves?  Anything that goes inside the {} curly braces for an attribute/prop on any element/component is just a JavaScript expression like any other, regardless of React.  If you're looking to add multiple classes, that expression just needs to result in a string that contains those classes.

You can apply the class to the selectedColor by passing selectedColor as a prop to the Color component, and additionally checking if selectedColor matches color, i.e:
const selected = selectedColor === color ? "selected" : ""; 

Below is a refactored code.
The colors have been extracted into a Colors state, and notice the use of .map to render the state items. This will help reduce redundancy and keep the code clean.
I have also added a bit of styling for visualization.
NB: You will notice that {color} was also added into the div in the Color component, this is so that you can see something by default.
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

const Color = ({ color, selectedColor, setSelectedColor }) => {
 const selected = selectedColor === color ? "selected" : "";
 return (
  <div
   className={`${color} ${selected}`}
   onClick={() => setSelectedColor(color)}
  >
   {color}
  </div>
 );
};

const App = () => {
 const colors = ["violet", "orange", "yellow"];
 const [selectedColor, setSelectedColor] = useState("");
 return (
  <div id="container">
   <div id="navbar">
    <div>Currently selected: </div>
    <div className={selectedColor}>{selectedColor}</div>
  </div>
  <div id="colors-list">
    {colors.map((color, index) => (
      <Color
        key={index}
        color={color}
        selectedColor={selectedColor}
        setSelectedColor={setSelectedColor}
      />
    ))}
   </div>
  </div>
 );
};

export default App;

CSS
.yellow,
.orange,
.violet {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected.yellow {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}

.selected.orange {
  border: 2px solid orange;
}

.selected.violet {
  border: 2px solid violet;
}


You need to add a variable to check if the color prop matches the selectedColor, and if they match you add the selected class, and with the ternary operator you can apply both the color and selected classes.
import { useState } from "react";
const Color = ({ color, setSelectedColor, selectedColor }) => {
  const isSelected = color === selectedColor ? "selected" : "";
  return (
    <div
      className={`${color} ${isSelected}`} // Apply both color and selected classes
      onClick={() => setSelectedColor(color)}
    ></div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [selectedColor, setSelectedColor] = useState("");

  return (
    <div id="container">
      <div id="navbar">
        <div>Currently selected: </div>
        <div className={selectedColor}>{selectedColor}</div>
      </div>
      <div id="colors-list">
        <Color color="violet" selectedColor={selectedColor} setSelectedColor={setSelectedColor} />
        <Color color="orange" selectedColor={selectedColor} setSelectedColor={setSelectedColor} />
        <Color color="yellow" selectedColor={selectedColor} setSelectedColor={setSelectedColor} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

